# Populate Integer Field based on Text Field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, attribute-table

Using ArcGIS 10.2.2

In the picture below, I want to populate the Spd_Class field (short integer). The value of the Spd_Class attribute will be based on the TYPE field -

residential = 30
secondary = 35
primary = 50

is there a quick way to use the text field in TYPE to populate Spd_Class? I've been unable to think of a way to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In your Field Calculator, have the python parser enabled.  You can do some neat things with the Field Calculator.  I suggest checking out the [Field Calculator Unleashed](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0405/files/fieldcalc_1.pdf) from ESRI for a bit of a code introduction to the Field Calculator.  Then check out [their documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004s000000) for more advanced ideas.

I am using `lower()` and `strip()` in case there are values that don't conform.

In the *Pre-Logic* part enter:

```
def myFunct(input):
  if input.lower().strip() == "residental":
    return 30
  elif input.lower().strip() == "secondary":
    return 35
  elif input.lower().strip() == "primary":
    return 50
```

In the bottom part, *Spd_Class* =

`myFunct(!TYPE!)`